# Touchscreen not working after standby Yoga 15

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, touchscreen

On my "Lenovo ThinkPad S5 Yoga 15" running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS I'm facing an issue concerning the touchscreen.
Issue:
Touchscreen not working after standby. The issue is caused by putting the device into standby. It does not matter whether this this is done by closing the lid or software.
When the issue occurs the touchscreen is unresponsive until a complete power off. Restarting the system, even when booting into windows doesn't fix the issue.
My Thoughts:
This suggests that it is caused during the "go to standby routine" and a solution should be found rather by investigation of the latter then trying to resurrect the screen after it "died".

Nonetheless there are some things I tried to resurrect the touch input:
1. I tried to reload kernel module hid_mutlitouch (doesn't exist on my device) and wacom
2. I exectuted /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m freeze -s 1 which was suggested somewhere else
3. Alt+Ctrl+F1 / Alt+Ctrl+F6 didn't work
xinput disable/enable (touchscreen ID) didn't work

ps: On windows there where absolutely no issues regarding the touchscreen and standby. Bios version is 1.32. A newer version is available but I couldn't boot the update utility from usb and I removed the windows install during some tests so I'm unable to update as for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but more so, touch input doesn't even work after wake from sleep on windows, after some digging i found out that it's likely a BIOS issue, this only started to happen when i turned 'Sleep State' to Linux in BIOS.

A temporary workaround could be switching the Sleep State back to Windows or Disabling Thunderbolt in IO/Devices under the security tab of the BIOS
i have a Thinkpad Yoga X1 3rd Gen dual-booting Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04 and this issue seems to be very common on Lenovo devices, still no fix though as of BIOS 1.40.

**EDIT :**
Using Linux power state and disabling Thunderbolt in BIOS does make the touchscreen work after sleep, and the lid wake up works as expected too, but you lose display out from the USB-C ports and any thunderbolt functionality like external GPU compatibility as mentioned by [@Sergey Sergeyev](https://askubuntu.com/users/360244/sergey-sergeyev).

If you open the lid and it does not wake your device when suspended, try running `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep LID`, if you see an entry with the name LID, enable it if it's saying it's disabled by editing /proc/acpi/wakeup file and changing `*disabled` to `*enabled`.

**EDIT 2:**
An even better solution with basically 0 compromises, is using this [hack](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Yoga_(Gen_3)#Fix_touchscreen_after_resume), it works well even with thunderbolt enabled in BIOS (although i should disclose that i did not try if it's really working or not since i do not possess any Thunderbolt ready devices).

Answer (score 1):

@mimminou With my dual boot Win10/Ubuntu_20.04 on ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 3 disabling Thunderbolt and switching sleep mode to Win10 at BIOS fixing the touchscreen awake issue but expect the following drawbacks:

- external USB-C display stops working through USB-C hub (display not detected and not switched on)
- notebook don't wake up on opening the lid. Power button pressing required.

Answer (score 0):

I have lenovo thinkpad x1 yoga gen 3 laptop. I experience the same issue described above - touchscreen does not work after system switches to sleep mode. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 - latest lenovo hardware drivers etc updated thru Ubuntu software update center. If I just close and reopen the laptop lid and login again, the touchscreen magically starts to work until he next  sleep cycle. OS details available below:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"    NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

Touch screen also was not working after sleep in Kali Linux (debian based distro)